# How to Specify ZoneUri in Dataproc's GceClusterConfig using Java SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataproc

When attempting to use Dataproc to create a new Compute cluster, it complains that when I specify a "real" zone such as "us-west1-a" or "us-central1-f", I receive an error message that the specified zone is not supported by this endpoint. (See error text below)

As you can see, according to the error, it expects the region to be "global". However, specifying it as global generates the error that "global" is not a valid zone. Doing silly things like specifying it as "[global]" just generates invalid URI formats. Not specifying a zone causes it to complain that the zone must be set.

All logical possible values are therefore eliminated, suggesting that there is some other step that must be taken to resolve this.

Error:

```
Reason: 400 Bad Request
{
   "errors" : [
      {
         "reason" : "badRequest",
         "domain" : "global",
         "message" : "Region us-central1-f invalid or not supported by this endpoint; permitted regions: [global]"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
   "code" : 400,
   "message" : "Region us-central1-f invalid or not supported by this endpoint; permitted regions: [global]"
}
```

The code snippet that generates this:

```
Cluster cluster = createClusterSpec();
createOp = dataproc.projects().regions().clusters()
           .create(projectId, region, cluster);
createOp.setBearerToken(credentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
createOp.execute();

// I'm cheating here: the actual code pulls the config from various
// inputs and properties, but we can replicate with hard-coded values.
private Cluster createClusterSpec() {
    GceClusterConfig computeEngineConfig = new GceClusterConfig();
    // ZONE_URI_FORMAT =
    //  "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%s/zones/%s"
    computeEngineConfig.setZoneUri(
        String.format(ZONE_URI_FORMAT, "funny-project-001",
                                       "us-central1-f"));
    InstanceGroupConfig masterConfig = new InstanceGroupConfig();
    masterConfig.setMachineTypeUri(
        String.format(MACHINE_TYPE_URI_FORMAT,
                      "funny-project-001", "us-central1-f",
                      "n1-standard-1"))
       .setNumInstances(1);
    InstanceGroupConfig workerConfig = new InstanceGroupConfig();
    workerConfig.setMachineTypeUri(
        String.format(MACHINE_TYPE_URI_FORMAT,
                      "funny-project-001", "us-central1-f",
                      "n1-standard-1"))

       .setNumInstances(1);


    ClusterConfig googClusterConfig = new ClusterConfig();
    googClusterConfig.setGceClusterConfig(computeEngineConfig);
    googClusterConfig.setMasterConfig(masterConfig);
    googClusterConfig.setWorkerConfig(workerConfig);
    Cluster returnVal = new Cluster();
    returnVal.setProjectId("funny-project-001");
    returnVal.setConfig(googClusterConfig);
    returnVal.setClusterName("mrfoo");
    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dataproc regions are specified independently from Compute Engine "zones" even though there is indeed a relationship between the two. For the time being, you are indeed only talking to the "global" Dataproc region, which knows how to serve all GCE zones. So you simply need to specify "global" as the argument to:

```
createOp = dataproc.projects().regions().clusters()
       .create(projectId, "global", cluster);
```

And then specify your GCE zone as the specific `us-central1-f` or whatever that you want. You can play around with the underlying JSON REST representation in console.cloud.google.com if you use Dataproc's UI to pick the options for creating a cluster, and then at the very bottom there's an "Equivalent REST" link.

You'll see something like:

```
POST /v1/projects/foo-project/regions/global/clusters/
{
   ...
   "gceClusterConfig": {
      "zoneUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/foo-project/zones/us-west1-a"
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

The `regions/global` in the POST URI is where the region argument goes in the SDK's `create(project, region, cluster)` method, while the body of `gceClusterConfig` is where you're setting `zoneUri` explicitly.